# How to erase a locked SSD

Tags: ssd, secure-erase, hdparm

I received 2 locked SSDs.
I managed to unfreeze them by a power cycle.

`hdparm` reports:

```
    supported
    enalbed
    locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
    supported: enchanced erase
```

Things I tried:

`sedutil`: one supports PSID revert but didn't work.
`secure erase w/ hdparm`: doesn't work.
`parted magic`: PSID unlock - got some results here, I got a green light.
It succeeds to unlock them w/ the right PSID, but I still can't erase them. `hdparm` reports the same as before.

Windows utils from Crucial and Samsung didn't work.

The models are:

1. Crucial MX500 1TB.
2. Samsung PM851 512GB.

They pass all SMART tests and they are in good health.
My goal is to erase them and repurpose them.
I believe they were nuked with Dban.

Edit: PSID is written on the label of the drives from the manufacturer.

Comment: Have you tried using [Crucial Storage Tool](http://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/support-storage-executive) to revert the PSID as described [here](https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/unlocking-the-physical-security-id-psid-of-a-crucial-ssd/)?

Comment: Tried and got an unsupported message, but I had it plugged in usb (working on a laptop). I'll try with desktop and have them both on sata. Will report back.

Comment: Have you tried the tool from "EaseUS" https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/remove-write-protection-ssd.html _Remove Write Protection from SSD, HDD, USB,_ etc. Supports Windows 10. Note: In most cases, it is better to __restart__ the machine after a format of a hard disk, before you attempt to use it, it helps when saving the partition and formatting.